# What's wrong with linux/if.h and net/if.h?

Tags: linux

In my project, I include pfring.h, but compile error: some functions in net/if.h and linux/if.h are redefinition. I found that the pfring.h include linux/if.h
So, I test a program, my test code:

```
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <net/if.h>

int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

It expected compile error.
So, what's wrong with linux/if.h and net/if.h ?
Can not I include them at once?

---

error message:

```
In file included from test.c:1:0:
/usr/include/linux/if.h:178:19: error: field 'ifru_addr' has incomplete type
/usr/include/linux/if.h:179:19: error: field 'ifru_dstaddr' has incomplete type
/usr/include/linux/if.h:180:19: error: field 'ifru_broadaddr' has incomplete type
/usr/include/linux/if.h:181:19: error: field 'ifru_netmask' has incomplete type
/usr/include/linux/if.h:182:20: error: field 'ifru_hwaddr' has incomplete type
In file included from test.c:2:0:
/usr/include/net/if.h:45:5: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
/usr/include/net/if.h:112:8: error: redefinition of 'struct ifmap'
/usr/include/linux/if.h:136:8: note: originally defined here
/usr/include/net/if.h:127:8: error: redefinition of 'struct ifreq'
/usr/include/linux/if.h:170:8: note: originally defined here
/usr/include/net/if.h:177:8: error: redefinition of 'struct ifconf'
/usr/include/linux/if.h:219:8: note: originally defined here
```

Comment: What is your need that requires both includes?

Comment: I include <boost/asio.hpp> witch include <net/if.h> implicit and I include <pfring.h> witch include <linux/if.h> implicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has been resolved, add the compile flag -DHAVE_PCAP is fix. ;-)

Comment: How can I apply this compile flag when not using a make file, just simply on the cli `g++ -o myapp myapp.cpp` ?

Comment: @jwbensley Just use g++ -o myapp myapp.cpp -DHAVE_PCAP. BTW, in boost 1.55 and pfring 5.6.1 there is no this conflict again.

Answer (score 21):

For me (on Ubuntu 12.04 x64) the following include solved the problem:

```c
#include <sys/socket.h> // <-- This one
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <linux/if_tun.h>
```

Comment: Ashwin's post http://algorithmicallyrandom.blogspot.sg/2012/07/error-on-including-include.html @hfmanson

Answer (score 2):

At first let us talk about the source: The header files are from different Packages as you can see asking `dpkg`.

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/include/linux/if.h
linux-libc-dev:i386: /usr/include/linux/if.h
$ dpkg -S /usr/include/net/if.h
libc6-dev:i386: /usr/include/net/if.h
```

`linux-libc-dev` is part of linux kernel packages while `libc6-dev` is part of the `libc6` (Standard C library in version 6).

It seams like they are interchangeable so you should only use one (not 100% sure about this). If you pick `linux/if.h`, you may depend on Kernel versions with your compiled binary.

All new Library versions I have in mind stick with `net/if.h` instead of the linux one - so you should do the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using one of the interface state flags (eg: IFF_UP, etc.), you need one more header than mentioned in other posts.

```
#include <sys/types.h>   // <== 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/if.h>
```